# Согласно чего?

Tags: синтаксис, управление

"Если вы не закрепите граватар за вашим электронным адресом, вам будет динамически добавлен местный граватар согласно установок сайта на котором он появляется".

"Согласно установок"... Можно было бы отнести к казённому сленгу, но это русский перевод западного сайта, ссылка на который ведет с данного ресурса!

Ваше мнение, коллеги?!

Answer (score 1):

"Согласно установок..." - это не казенный сленг, а просто неграмотная фраза, так как предлоги "согласно, вопреки, благодаря" требуют дательного падежа.